# Where can I cancel my newsstand subscriptions?

Tags: itunes, newsstand

I recently subscribed to a newsstand magazine. The confirmation e-mail stated that my subscription will be **renewed automatically**. I don't want this, but I can't find the option to **turn this off**. It's not under 'Purchases'...

So where can I **manage my subscriptions**? Is there a generic way to do this in the iTunes store?

Comment: Is there not any information in the confirmation email?

Comment: @EmmEff Yes, but I doubt I'll be able to find that email in one year's time, when the subscription ends... There must be another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Settings` then choose `Store`.  There you will find a list of your current subscriptions, which you can turn to "off" if you no longer wish to subscribe to a given product.

Some users have indicated that there are still issues, such as unsubscribing, then going back into settings --> store and finding they are still subscribed, but this seems to be rare, and I expect it will be resolved.

There are also usually contact options to reach the developer of the product in the newstand store, just like contact options in the app store.  You can contact the developer directly for support if their app doesn't seem to be successfully unsubscribing.

Most newstand subscriptions should have an interface to unsubscribe in the app itself, or under the app in `Settings`.

Due to the way subscriptions work in the App Store, though, a developer would have to add a non-recurring subscription option to their app.  I imagine most won't - they will only offer their subscriptions under the app store's auto-renewal process.

You should contact the developers directly if you wish them to add a non-recurring purchase option.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the store under `My Account` -> `Settings` -> `Subscriptions`

Comment: If you are reading the same magazine from several devices, don't forget to turn the setting off on all devices.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a service called [BillNina.com](https://www.billninja.com) to cancel iTunes and other subscriptions.

Comment: Flagged as spam.

Comment: @Ryan please disclose any affiliations when posting on Ask Different. Leaving this answer here for now since it does seem to answer the question being asked.